# Is there Autoscaling in JavaFX?

Tags: layout, javafx, autoscaling, scenebuilder

Is there any autoscaling for my layouts in javafx or do I have to rescale everything programmatically?

Comment: Why is this closed? It's a very valid question as it is not obvious how to auto-scale a JavaFX scene (it *is* possible).

Comment: Probably because some SO admins get a dopamine burst when closing a question as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX works with a scene graph. On every node of the graph you can specify transformations (for example rotation, translation, scaling, etc.). If you set a scale transformation on the root node, then automatically everything in the whole scene graph will be scaled. You do not need to scale every component in your scene separately.

Comment: I have used those fxml files for my layouts in my application. If I toogle fullscreen,all inner layouts still have the old size and seem to align to the left of the scene

Answer (score 1):

Set the AnchorPane Constraints on Scenebuilder for the nodes you want to dynamically resize with its parent AnchorPane.